# Как обработать в скрипте переданные ему параметры?

Tags: ruby

программа должна принимать 4 аргумента и запускаться

```
$ ruby if.rb 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать класс `ARGV`, входящий в стандартную библиотеку Ruby.
У этого класса есть метод `[]`, который позволяет обращаться к параметрам комендной строки, переданным через пробел, как к массиву.

При запуске скрипта строкой `ruby my_script.rb one_param two_param   ...`, внутри скрипта, `ARGV[0]` - вернет строку "one_param", `ARGV[1]` - "two_param", `ARGV[2]` - "...". Количество пробелов между передаваемыми параметрами не имеет значения.

Подробнее тут:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ARGF.html